How to set fixed value for y-axis using elixir library called contex?
Hello fellow learners.
I am creating charts in my Elixir project, using a Elixir library ContEx - https://hexdocs.pm/contex/Contex.html
I have created a Bar chart. In that chart, I want to set the highest tick value of the y-axis to 56. I have used tick_positions to do it. But my chart looks messy.
enter image description here
This is my chart. I have also found that the range in context is used to set the range axis. But I don’t how to do it in my code. So how should I use range in my code to set range for my y-axis?
      options = [
        custom_value_scale:
          Contex.ContinuousLogScale.new(
            domain: {0, 56},
            tick_positions: [5, 10, 15, 20, 40, 56],
            negative_numbers: :mask
          ),
          colour_palette: ["ffdfae"],
          data_labels: false,
        ]

Even if the values for the bars are less than 56, I need the 56 to appear.
I want to find out how should i have static values for the y-axis. I want the range of the y-axis as 0 to 56. How should I do it?

Here is a working LiveView that renders this image:

defmodule MyAppWeb.ExampleBarChartLive do
  use Phoenix.LiveView

  alias Contex.BarChart
  alias Contex.ContinuousLinearScale
  alias Contex.Dataset
  alias Contex.Plot

  def mount(_params, _session, socket) do
    socket
    |> make_test_data()
    |> then(&{:ok, &1})
  end

  def render(assigns) do
    ~H"""
    <div>
      <%= plot_test_data(@test_data) %>
    </div>
    """
  end

  def plot_test_data(test_data) do
    custom_value_scale =
      ContinuousLinearScale.new()
      |> ContinuousLinearScale.interval_count(14)
      |> ContinuousLinearScale.domain(0, 56)

    options = [
      mapping: %{category_col: "Category", value_cols: ["Series"]},
      type: :stacked,
      data_labels: true,
      orientation: :vertical,
      select_item: nil,
      custom_value_scale: custom_value_scale,
      default_style: false
    ]

    plot =
      Plot.new(test_data, BarChart, 225, 180, options)
      |> Plot.titles("", "")
      |> Plot.axis_labels("", "")
      |> Plot.plot_options(%{})

    Plot.to_svg(plot)
  end

  defp make_test_data(socket) do
    data = [
      ["Harmony", 15],
      ["Perfection", 15],
      ["Strength", 16],
      ["Wisdom", 15]
    ]

    series_cols = ["Series"]

    test_data = Dataset.new(data, ["Category" | series_cols])

    assign(socket, test_data: test_data)
  end
end

Note:
I set default_style to false.
Then I added this to the app.css file in my project:
text {
    font-size: 0.5rem;
}

